# Try/catch within a closure gives an error

Tags: typescript

This simple try/catch within a closure gives an error on compiling with TypeScript:

```
type TryCatchFn = (args: any, context: any) => void;

function try_catch(fn: TryCatchFn): TryCatchFn {
    return (args, context) => void {
        try {
            throw new Error('Something bad happened');
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
data/src/cloud_scripts.ts:12:7 - error TS1005: ':' expected.

12      try {
            ~


data/src/cloud_scripts.ts:13:10 - error TS1005: ':' expected.

13              throw new Error('Something bad happened');
                      ~~~


data/src/cloud_scripts.ts:13:45 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

13              throw new Error('Something bad happened');
                                                         ~


data/src/cloud_scripts.ts:14:5 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

14      } catch (e) {
          ~~~~~
```

However, if I rewrite it to not call the fn function, then there are no errors:

```
type TryCatchFn = (args: any, context: any) => void;

function try_catch(fn: TryCatchFn): void {
    try {
        throw new Error('Something bad happened');
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Obviously, the above rewrite breaks the function. I'm just curious what I'm doing wrong in the first case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write:

```
return (args, context) => void { ... }
```

this is being interpreted as an arrow function with an expression body. The `void` operator evaluates the following expression then throws the result away, so this is a function that returns `undefined`. The expression in this case is an object literal, and `try` isn't valid in an object literal.

Without the `void`

```
return (args, context) => { ... }
```

would be an arrow function with a block statement body. Your `try` will work fine here. If you don't return anything from the block you don't need to explicitly give the return type, but you can if you want:

```
return (args, context): void => { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

The type annotation for the return type of an arrow function must come after the parameter list and before the `=>`:

```
type TryCatchFn = (args: any, context: any) => void;

function try_catch(fn: TryCatchFn): TryCatchFn {
    return (args, context): void => {
        try {
            throw new Error('Something bad happened');
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can leave the return type out altogether:

```
function try_catch(fn: TryCatchFn): TryCatchFn {
    return (args, context) => {
        try {
            throw new Error('Something bad happened');
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
}
```